# How do you construct an integration that populates the Application on Login?

Tags: api

We have a lot of custom integrations to Salesforce that use the same user credentials and I would like to be able to tell which is which. I've seen managed packages that declare who they are with a name in the Application field on Login History. How do you populate that when authorizing?

[image: Image of Login History record with Login Type, Status and Application columns]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your integrations are authenticating with Salesforce using OAuth, you would need to create a new Connected App and have the authentication scheme pass in your app's Client Identifier in the `client_id` parameter and its Client Secret in the `client_secret` parameter.

More information can be found here: [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)